# Killing a pid tree in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, pid

I have a script that loads a few programs but refuses to exit when given `kill -15` and if I use `kill -9` all of the child processes stay running.

I have tried:

```
parent=$(pgrep -f ./start_server.sh)
children=$(pgrep -P $parent)
sudo kill -9 $children $parent &
```

and this kills MOST of the pids (2964 2976 2977 2978 2979). Problem being is sometimes one of the children will have its own children and those will still be running (2976 has 10, etc).

What I mean when I say they keep running is for example: `kill -9 2964` will cause `2976 2977 2978 2979` to become children of `2738`

Also, the above code causes the script its in to exit as soon as the `kill` command returns (and print `Killed` to the console). I tried to run it by adding a `&` or `exec` but the script will still immediately exit.

At the end of the day I have this `./start_server.sh` started via initd and when it crashes it can not restart properly because of these orphaned processes. I want to put a line in start that will murder all the processes that it spawned.

[image: PID's Screenshot]

Comment: Can you start killing the child processes first?

Comment: Does `pkill node` work? (I can do `pkill java` to kill all instances of JVM on my machine but don't know about node)

Comment: @Arash pkil node kills all node instances which is to global for my application.

Comment: @codeforester even if i kill the children the qty can be different so there are inevitably stranded processes. Why on earth is killing the parent not enough?